# Angular testing and HttpClient: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-httpclient

In my Angular 4 application I need to create a test for a component which uses a service which internally uses the angular HttpClient.

Despite I added `HttpClientTestingModule` between the `imports` of my `TestBed`, I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

whenever the component calls `MyService.someMethod()` (which internally uses `HttpClient.get()`).

I tried providing the service itself or providing a mock for it, but I'm getting the error anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem:

I needed to remove `{ provide: AuthService, useClass: MockAuthService }`, from my `TestBed`'s `providers` list. It is no longer needed and somehow was interfering with the `HttpClientTestingModule`.

Comment: I only have this code in spec file:
providers: [{provide: http}],
But still getting the same error, any idea ?